# SSH.NET CreateShellStream()

Tags: c#, ssh, windows-console, ssh.net

I am building an application, SWSH, which is a ssh client. 
I am having trouble using the `CreateShellStream()` function.

My code:

```
using (var ssh = new SshClient(ccinfo))
{
    var keepgoing = true;
    ssh.Connect();
    string terminalName = "xterm-256color";
    uint columns = 80;
    uint rows = 160;
    uint width = 80;
    uint height = 160;
    // arbitrarily chosen
    int bufferSize = 500;
    IDictionary<Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes, uint> terminalModeValues = null;
    var actual = ssh.CreateShellStream(terminalName, columns, rows, width, height, bufferSize, terminalModeValues);
    //Read Thread
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        while (actual.CanRead)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(actual.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                keepgoing = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        keepgoing = false;
    }).Start();
    //Write Thread
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        while (actual.CanWrite)
        {
            try
            {
                actual.WriteLine("");
                actual.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                keepgoing = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        keepgoing = false;
    }).Start();
}
```

I can render the output correctly but problem is in how it behaves.
[image: swsh]

Problem #1:

```
root:~/ # Cant write here
```

Problem #2: Double commands.

What am I doing wrong?

GitHub link: https://github.com/muhammadmuzzammil1998/SWSH/blob/43c17e95e684e6a3bced67bc7db04e6697972394/SWSH/Program.cs#L286