# SSH.NET retrieving output from ShellStream

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I am new to SSH.NET and I am using it in a project that I am currently working on.

I have to run a sudo command using SSH.NET and that is why I am using ShellStream to run the command and provide authentication for the sudo command. Now I am trying to run a sudo command that finds a file in a directory on the server that I ssh to. The command is as follows:

```
sudo -S find -name 29172
```

This command is supposed to output a path that indicates where the file is located as follows:

`./output/directory/29172`

The problem that I am having now is that when I do this through shell stream I do not know how to get the output. And even when I try to read the ShellStream I end up with this:

```
var client = new SshClient(IP, username, password);

var stream = client.CreateShellStream("input", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000000);

stream.WriteLine("sudo -S find . -name 29172");

stream.WriteLine("\"" +password+"\"");

var output = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

What output usually gives is a description of when I logged into the server using `SSH.NET` and then the commands that I provided to the system:

```
"Last login: Mon Sep 23 15:23:35 2019 from 100.00.00.00\r\r\nserver@ubuntu-dev4:~$ sudo -S find . -name 29172\r\n[sudo] password for server: \r\n"
```

I am not looking for this output, rather I am looking for the actual output of the command such as `"./output/directory/29172"` from the ShellStream. Would anyone know how to do this? Thank you for reading and I hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: You created a string for input, do you need to also for output?

Comment: `stream.WriteLine("\"" +password+"\"");` – Why the double-quotes? It should be simply `stream.WriteLine(password);`

Comment: And in general, automating `sudo` is a bad approach. See [Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663).

Comment: As an aside, make sure you're deterministically disposing of `stream` and `client` by employing the `using` construct.

Comment: Thank you all for responding. @jdweng I created a string for input but I need the actual output of the command ran on the ssh. I was just wondering if that was possible.

Comment: And yes @Jesse C.Slicer I am using the using keyword thank you for the tip. I just did not put it because I thought it was not necessary for my example.

Comment: Also @MartinPrikryl I will read what you posted. Thank you for the input

Comment: Following has both actual.Readline and actual.Writeline : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041574/ssh-net-createshellstream

Answer (score 3):

My solution is quite lengthy but it does a few other necessary things to reliably run commands over ssh:

- automatically respond to authentication requests
- captures error codes and throw on failures

To automate sudo over SSH we can use `Expect` - this is like the linux tool of the same name and lets you respond to interactively. It waits until there is some output that matches a pattern e.g. a password prompt.

If you have a series of sudo operations you can be caught by the unpredictable amount of time until sudo requires reauthentication so sudo might or might not need authentication, we can't be sure.

A big issue when automating is to know whether a command fails or not. The only way to know is to get the last error over the shell. I throw on non-zero.

The regex to match the shell prompt might need to be customized for your configuration. All sorts of things might be injected into the prompt.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Common;

namespace Example
{
    public class Log
    {
        public static void Verbose(string message) =>
            Console.WriteLine(message);

        public static void Error(string message) =>
            Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public static class StringExt
    {
        public static string StringBeforeLastRegEx(this string str, Regex regex)
        {
            var matches = regex.Matches(str);

            return matches.Count > 0
                ? str.Substring(0, matches.Last().Index)
                : str;

        }

        public static bool EndsWithRegEx(this string str, Regex regex)
        {
            var matches = regex.Matches(str);

            return
                matches.Count > 0 &&
                str.Length == (matches.Last().Index + matches.Last().Length);
        }

        public static string StringAfter(this string str, string substring)
        {
            var index = str.IndexOf(substring, StringComparison.Ordinal);

            return index >= 0
                ? str.Substring(index + substring.Length)
                : "";
        }

        public static string[] GetLines(this string str) =>
            Regex.Split(str, "\r\n|\r|\n");
    }

    public static class UtilExt
    {
        public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> func) 
        {
            foreach (var item in sequence)
            {
                func(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Ssh
    {
        SshClient sshClient;
        ShellStream shell;
        string pwd = "";
        string lastCommand = "";

        static Regex prompt = new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*\\@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*\\:\\~[#$] ", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        static Regex pwdPrompt = new Regex("password for .*\\:", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        static Regex promptOrPwd = new Regex(Ssh.prompt + "|" + Ssh.pwdPrompt);

        public void Connect(string url, int port, string user, string pwd)
        {
            Log.Verbose($"Connect Ssh: {user}@{pwd}:{port}");

            var connectionInfo =
                new ConnectionInfo(
                    url,
                    port,
                    user,
                    new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(user, pwd));

            this.pwd = pwd;
            this.sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
            this.sshClient.Connect();

            var terminalMode = new Dictionary<TerminalModes, uint>();
            terminalMode.Add(TerminalModes.ECHO, 53);

            this.shell = this.sshClient.CreateShellStream("", 0, 0, 0, 0, 4096, terminalMode);

            try
            {
                this.Expect(Ssh.prompt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Exception - " + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            Log.Verbose($"Ssh Disconnect");

            this.sshClient?.Disconnect();
            this.sshClient = null;
        }

        void Write(string commandLine)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Log.Verbose("> " + commandLine);
            Console.ResetColor(); 

            this.lastCommand = commandLine;

            this.shell.WriteLine(commandLine);
        }

        string Expect(Regex expect, double timeoutSeconds = 60.0)
        {
            var result = this.shell.Expect(expect, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds));

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Timeout {timeoutSeconds}s executing {this.lastCommand}");
            }

            result = result.Contains(this.lastCommand) ? result.StringAfter(this.lastCommand) : result;
            result = result.StringBeforeLastRegEx(Ssh.prompt);
            result = result.Trim();

            result.GetLines().ForEach(x => Log.Verbose(x));

            return result;
        }

        public string Execute(string commandLine, double timeoutSeconds = 30.0)
        {
            Exception exception = null;
            var result = "";
            var errorMessage = "failed";
            var errorCode = "exception";

            try
            {
                this.Write(commandLine);
                result = this.Expect(Ssh.promptOrPwd);

                if (result.EndsWithRegEx(pwdPrompt))
                {
                    this.Write(this.pwd);
                    this.Expect(Ssh.prompt);
                }

                this.Write("echo $?");
                errorCode = this.Expect(Ssh.prompt);

                if (errorCode == "0")
                {
                    return result;    
                }
                else if (result.Length > 0)
                {
                    errorMessage = result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exception = ex;
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
            }

            throw new Exception($"Ssh error: {errorMessage}, code: {errorCode}, command: {commandLine}", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```cs
var client = new Ssh(IP, 22, username, password);

var output = client.Execute("sudo -S find . -name 29172");
```

Comment: ShellStream.Expect returns a string, but your Expect method calls var result = this.shell.Expect and then uses the result.StringAfter() and result.StringBeforeLastRegEx() method, which don't exist.   What is this attempting to do here?

Comment: See the `StringExt` class in the example. They are string extensions for extracting substrings to e.g. strip shell prompts, strip the echoed command and identify password prompts.