# SSH.NET retrieving output from ShellStream, minicom does not return anything

Tags: c#, ssh.net, minicom

I was able to successfully connect using this example [SSH.NET retrieving output from ShellStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065938/ssh-net-retrieving-output-from-shellstream?newreg=e79c483e7f5f442fb7384102d8a590e8) and run all commands and process the results. I only have problems after I send the command `minicom -D /dev/ttyUSBx`. Nothing returns. Following the putty settings (SSH->TTY) I tried to use various `TerminalModes` but nothing worked. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What output is shown, wenn you execute the exact command using SSH over putty?

Comment: look at this [link](https://wiki.bu.ost.ch/infoportal/_media/software/linux/minicom_overview.png), the output is similar